# Javascript string interpolation to create SQL query with Array

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, postgresql, string-interpolation

I want to create a SQL query to select all records where values are in an array of strings. 
say I have the following array

`myarray = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

I want to use this to construct a query like this

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mycol IN ('a', 'b', 'c')`

Regular string interpolation obviously does not work for this. I even tried [sql-bricks](https://csnw.github.io/sql-bricks/#selwhere) but apparently it does not support IN with WHERE.

Is there a good way to use arrays in SQL queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let sql = `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mycol IN ('${ myarray.join("','") }');`
```

Also, if you want to remove null-values:

```
let myarray = ['a', 'b', null, 'c']
let sql = `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mycol IN ('${ 
myarray.filter(function (el) {
  return el != null;
}).join("','")
 }');`
```

==>

> "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mycol IN ('a','b','c');"

Also, to avoid sql-injection, you should first map myarray to an array where ' has been replaced with ''.

.ie.

```
let myarray = ['a', 'b', null, 'c', "d'Alambert"]
.filter(function (el) { return el != null; })
.map(function(el){ return el.replace(/'/g, "''");}); 

let sql = `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mycol IN ('${ myarray.join("','") }');`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This sure works. I am surprised to not find any more elegant way to do this.. given that this is such a standard use case.